# Quantidade máxima de elementos enviado por um formulário?

Tags: html, http, post, get

Gostaria de saber se existe uma quantidade máxima de elementos que eu posso mandar de um formulário a outro via `POST` assim como via `GET`.

Sei que se eu passar meus dados via `GET`, existe um comprimento máximo de `URL`, variando de acordo com o navegador, mas via `POST` isso me parece meio obscuro...

Um trecho do **[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)**:

> POST requests have no restrictions on data length

Isso é uma verdade absoluta? Não existe uma restrição máxima?

Comment: Isso não é [W3C](http://www.w3.org/) é [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

Comment: É que são bem diferentes, e conhecidos por razões bem diferentes. W3C é confiável. O w3schools nem por isso.

Comment: Se for no PHP, a diretiva do php.ini é quem define isso. N caso, é definido pela diretiva `max_post_size ` o limite de dados enviados no post (em Megabites)

Comment: No caso, como não tem a tag php na sua postagem, preferi generalizar a resposta :)

Comment: A idéia da pergunta é meio genérica mesmo.... como os dados são passados pelo cabeçalho de uma requisição `Cliente-Servidor`, deve provavelmente existir um tamanho máximo de informações do POST para a transferência, em cada fonte que busco acho uma informação diferente.

Comment: Como eu disse: É bom ter um limite. No php, por exemplo, o POST é convertido num array. Um array gigante gera um estouro de memória. Dá pra fazer um overhead em alguns casos, rsrsrsrs

Comment: @MarceloBoni nenhuma é boa ou esqueceu desta? Se eu puder melhorar algo é só dizer.

Comment: @bigown eu tinha me esquecido completamente dela =]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O que você realmente deve observar é o limite do mais fraco, qual é o menor limite entre todos os componentes envolvidos no processo.

Para o URL, mesmo que outros componentes aceitem um limite superior a 2048 bytes, o Internet Explorer não consegue enviar mais, portanto você deve trabalhar com esse limite a não ser que seja garantindo que nenhum usuário vá usar o IE, o que é bem pouco provável. Mesmo assim eu ainda ficaria com esse limite para garantir. Tanto para o GET, quanto para o POST, este é o limite que o URL deve ter, mas com o POST é possível enviar dados além do URL, O GET, só envia pelo URL.

O protocolo HTTP não impõe limite algum para o envio de dados via POST. Mas o servidor HTTP pode estar configurado para algum limite.

Em tese nenhum *browser* impõe algum limite.

O PHP costuma ter um limite relativamente baixo que funciona na maior parte das vezes. Outras linguagens podem ter alguma limitação.

Mesmo se você resolver mudar este limite do PHP ou do servidor HTTP, pense bem, isto pode trazer problemas. Não é fácil manipular grandes envios de dados. Fora que o envio pode ter problemas no meio, então tanto o servidor quanto o cliente precisam saber lidar com isto. Talvez seja melhor fracionar o envio se os dados a serem enviados forem muito grandes, e obviamente precisa gerenciar reenvios.

Então o limite de elementos não é o que importa. Se você já tem vários elementos e somados eles são muito grandes, é melhor enviar de forma separada, se possível.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 7):

**Não existe limite**, mas tanto o interpretador da linguagem quanto o servidor podem restringir.

No caso do POST em PHP, existe uma linha no `php.ini` que determina isso.

```
; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
post_max_size = 8M
```

Por padrão é 8 mega geralmente, mas cada hospedagem trata de uma forma diferente, então vale se atentar a isso caso haja necessidade no seu projeto.

**Porém,** o servidor pode restringir isso também. No caso do `apache`, por exemplo, fica aqui: `LimitRequestBody` e `LimitRequestFieldSize`. Em outros servidores, as configurações variam.

Comment: O problema é se o cara não estiver falando do PHP, e sim de todas todas linguagens no geral (não tem a tag **php** no post dele)

Comment: Verdade, Wallace.

Answer (score 5):

Tecnicamente existe uma restrição por pacote enviado para executar uma request.

A rede é dividida em camadas, enumeradas a seguir:

1. Camada de aplicação
2. Camada de transporte
3. Camada de rede
4. Camada de enlace
5. Camada física

Enquanto que na camada de aplicação não existe limites para quantidade de informações enviadas, isso não impede dela ser fragmentada para ser enviada pela internet.

Em suma: **não** existe um limite de dados a ser enviado, mas **existe** um limite de dados a ser enviado por pacote para responder a sua requisição. E isso é feito de forma automática pelas máquinas que se encarregam de enviar a requisição, como roteadores e modems.

Answer (score 3):

O POST não possui limite de dados a serem enviados. No entanto, seu servidor pode ter configurado um limite de dados que pode receber via POST. Por exemplo, no PHP o limite padrão é 2Mb.

Comment: É bom ter um limite. Pois eu já consegui fazer um "pequeno ataque" utilizando um formulário "gigante" (64 arrays dentro do outro multiplicado por 2000 vezes, rsrsrsrsrs)

Comment: Um servidor com um limite grande para envio de dados via POST é um convite para ataques DDoS =)