# Tamanho maximo de Array passado por POST

Tags: php, javascript

Estou fazendo uma função `JavaScript` para ler um arquivo que o usuário esta fazendo o upload e mando para o `PHP` via `POST` apenas o conteúdo para a inserção no banco.

Estou tentando mandar um `array` com o conteúdo do arquivo, cada posição é uma linha, o problema é que alguns arquivos podem ser muito grandes (600 mil linhas) e o maior `array` que consigo passar via `POST` é 100 mil linhas.
Já mudei no `php.ini` `post_max_size`, `max_input_vars`, `memory_limit` mas ainda assim não consigo.

Alguém sabe como faço para passar esse `array` com 600 mil posições por `POST` sem ter que quebra-lo em partes?

Comment: Possível relacionamento: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47145/quantidade-m%C3%A1xima-de-elementos-enviado-por-um-formul%C3%A1rio

Comment: Ansioso por boas respostas, achei uma ótima pergunta rs +1

Comment: Eu não entendi o javascript, você quer dizer "ajax"?

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio Sim eu sei o que é Ajax. A questão nada fala de JavaScript diretamente, não dá para saber se é vários inputs gerados ou se a transmissão é feita por `XMLHttpRequest`.

Answer (score 1):

A sua descrição indica que você pode estar enfrentando uma restrição do patch Suhosin do PHP.

Existem outras duas diretivas que devem ser adicionadas/alteradas se este módulo estiver ativo: `suhosin.post.max_vars` e `suhosin.request.max_vars`, além das já informadas na pergunta.

Tente alterar essas diretivas no php.ini.

Fontes: [esta pergunta no SO inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807100/post-max-array-size) e [PHP 5.3 max_input_vars and big forms](https://anothersysadmin.wordpress.com/2012/02/16/php-5-3-max_input_vars-and-big-forms/)