# Existe limite de tamanho dos dados transmitidos via POST?

Tags: http

Enviei um formulário via GET com um número grande de texto (uns 6 mil caracteres) e recebi um erro de URL muito longa.

Fiz o mesmo teste via POST e os dados foram enviados com sucesso.

Minha dúvida é se existe um limite de dados a ser transmitido via POST, pois GET eu já sei que é limitado.

Comment: Relacionada, **se** não duplicada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47145/quantidade-m%C3%A1xima-de-elementos-enviado-por-um-formul%C3%A1rio

Comment: Amigo, antes de postar uma duvida, certifique que a mesma já não possui aqui no strackoverflow, buscando por palavras chaves no campo de pesquisa, ex limite post

Comment: Relacionada também, **se** não for duplicada: [Problema com URL muito grande](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/35576/66203)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Problema com URL muito grande](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35573/problema-com-url-muito-grande)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Em teoria o limite máximo de uma requisição post é ilimitado. O limite real depende de cada aplicação servidora. O Mateus já deu a dica de como isso pode ser configurado em ambientes Linux (dos quais eu não entendo nada).

Para aplicações rodando no IIS da Microsoft, você define o limite através do painel do IIS ou do arquivo *web.config* da aplicação.

Não vou me estender aqui sobre como fazer essas configurações, mas pela [documentação](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits) o limite **padrão** de requisições é de trinta milhões de bytes (aproximadamente **28.6MB**). Já o limite máximo configurável é de 4.294.967.295 bytes, aproximamente **4GB**.

Já o nodejs trabalha com um limite padrão de requisições de **80KB** (vide a variável HTTP_MAX_HEADER_SIZE no [código fonte](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/deps/http_parser/http_parser.h)). Middlewares como o [Connect](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect) permitem definir limites maiores, mas aí o limite máximo configurável vai variar de middleware para middleware.

Answer (score 3):

Depende da configuração do server. Se você estiver trabalhando com `PHP` em um Linux ou algo similar você pode controlar isso configurando o `.htaccess`

```
#Set o tamanho maximo de um post
php_value post_max_size 15M
```

Mas se estiver utilizando IIS eu não tenho ideia de como fazer-lo.

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364840/what-is-the-size-limit-of-a-post-request)